# breadcrumbs in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, breadcrumbs

I am using joomla 1.5 version with beez template. How can we use breadcrumbs in this.I am new to this CMS. How to create our owm list in breadcrumbs.Can anyone help me

Comment: if you want to create your own breadcrumb then you have to create a module for your joomla template.

Comment: I have created module as shown in below link but i am not able to see breacrumbs http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzGejdy5CNY

Comment: have you enabled it from the modules manager??

Comment: yes i have enabled it from modules manager

Comment: and have to implement it from into the template from where you want to see your breadcrumb??

Comment: Have you created any pages? Breadcrumbs will show when you have few pages/links. Something could be missing in CSS? Are you able to show us a demo?

Answer (score 1):

here is how to implement the joomla module into your template

first you have to implement this code into your templates/template_dir/index.php:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadCrumb" />
```

then go to the `templateDetails.xml` and set the name of your module into this xml file:

```
<positions>
            <position>breadcrumb</position>
            <position>left</position>
            <position>right</position>
            <position>breadCrumb</position>
            <position>user1</position>
            <position>user2</position>
            <position>user3</position>
            <position>user4</position>
            <position>footer</position>
    </positions>
```

then you can find the name `breadCrumb` into your admin panel / module manager / positions

just simply apply the name and view the template..

to know more about this please follow the link http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template